# Take 3 columns and turn to 2 columns with stack()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not quite understanding the use of stack() function or how to implement it in this specific way. And in fact, maybe stack isn't even the right way to look at this. But I tried it, and it got me close to what I'm looking for.

I'm try to get this dataframe:

```
gid     v    h
4791    ATL  PHI
4792    BUF  BAL
4793    PIT  CLE
4794    CIN  IND
4795    TEN  MIA
4796    SF   MIN
4797    HOU  NE
4798    TB   NO
4799    JAC  NYG
4800    KC   LAC
```

Using `df.stack()` gets me close to what I want, but not exactly. I'm not sure how to use the columns as arguments to work it out. I could just iterate by the rows of the dataframe, but I feel that's probably not the quickest, most efficient way. I only want the last 2 columns stacked with the first column `gid` repeated. For example, this is the output I'm try to get:

```
gid     team
4791    ATL 
4791    PHI
4792    BUF
4792    BAL
4793    PIT
4793    CLE
4794    CIN
4794    IND
4795    TEN
4795    MIA
4796    SF
4796    MIN
4797    HOU
4797    NE
4798    TB
4798    NO
4799    JAC
4799    NYG
4800    KC
4800    LAC
```

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()` should give you a data frame which is easy to play with and get to your result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first, last double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove level of `MultiIndex` and for column from `index`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('gid').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='team')
```

Or use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), but then values are not sorted, so [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) is necessary:

```
df1 = (df.melt('gid', value_name='team')
         .sort_values('gid')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
print (df1)
     gid team
0   4791  ATL
1   4791  PHI
2   4792  BUF
3   4792  BAL
4   4793  PIT
5   4793  CLE
6   4794  CIN
7   4794  IND
8   4795  TEN
9   4795  MIA
10  4796   SF
11  4796  MIN
12  4797  HOU
13  4797   NE
14  4798   TB
15  4798   NO
16  4799  JAC
17  4799  NYG
18  4800   KC
19  4800  LAC
```

Comment: actually, he should pass drop=False in reset_index , since he wanted to duplicate values